# Can't send e-mail to hotmail addresses

Tags: php, hotmail

I recently did a mailing to a lot of hotmail addresses and now all the e-mails I send out (from PHP by the way) don't seem to reach their destination. So I figure hotmail banned my url...

Is there any way to get rid of this ban so my e-mails will reach the users again (like activation e-mails etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server IP is blocked by Hotmail, try using an alternate SMTP to send the messages temporarily. Maybe Gmail's SMTP? if you have a Gmail account of course. Don't abuse it though.

I am almost 100% sure that Hotmail will remove your IP eventually from the blacklist. Most services run a 48-72 hours ban; if they don't receive any more requests from the banned IP, it will get removed from the list.

Comment: Ok, I will temporarily send the e-mails from my other domain by hand. Hope they will remove me from the blacklist soon :)

Comment: Seems like you are right, the ban is gone now and mails are reaching the hotmail accounts again... thnx

Answer (score 0):

Is your domain really banned? Didn't those emails just end up in junk folder? If the former, then you'll really need to contact Hotmail. Either way, I recommend you to read [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) to avoid ending up in junk folder or to get banned again in the future.

Comment: Nope, it's not the junk folder stuff... I tried to send to my own hotmail address and the mails simply don't arrive.

Comment: Been there. I seriously doubt your domain is blocked. Try swiftmailer.

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter mail class...

The e-mail used to arrive, until I decided to do that stupid mailing... After about 200 emails (in 2 hours) they started to bounce back. Haven't been able to send any since then (I already disabled the mailing)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a mailing class like [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)? I've found it solves most issues.

Comment: I'm using swiftmailer as part of the Symfony2 framework. Emails to hotmail aren't making it, but to other accounts they are. So it seems like a blacklist issue to me. :(